# Can't install dlib

Tags: python, dlib

Hi I'm trying to install dlib in VSCode, with pip install dlib, but it gave me this error. Wondering if anyone can help

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\users\admin\documents\python\pyai3.6\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j42ksv_7\dlib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y1xi59yt\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
--install-headers c:\users\admin\documents\python\pyai3.6\include\site\python3.6\dlib" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j42ksv_7\dlib\

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO, please try to avoid posting large blocks of unformatted text, as this is difficult to read and will dissuade readers from helping

Comment: You seem to have a lot of duplicated messages, please edit your post to make it more readable. Also, if you read through your trace, you see `Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit` - you're using a 64-bit Visual Studio prompt/environment. You need to change to 32-bit (or install a 64-bit Python).

Comment: i also get the same error. i have install same 64 bit python package and 64 vscode

Comment: @wkl ah thanks, I just checked and yeah, I accidentally installed the 32-bit version instead of 64-bit. Everything's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I installed the 32-bit version of python instead of 64-bit. I just need to download the 64-bit version and run that.